# Deactivate mousepad while typing in KDE

Tags: kde, mouse, cursor

I am using KDE 4.13.3 on my Laptop and whenever I'm typing the cursor jumps to different places, because I accidentally touch the mousepad with my thumb. This is super annoying and other window managers have an option to disable the mousepad while typing.

How do I do this with KDE?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using synaptics touchpad. If so install `xf86-input-synaptics` driver, which comes with `syndaemon` tool:

> syndaemon - a program that monitors keyboard activity and disables the
>   touchpad when the keyboard is being used

Once installed you can start it with `-d` (daemon) option. It is also possible to configure some settings like delay before re-enabling touchpad after last keyboard key was pressed.

Comment: This only works for old Ubuntu and Mint versions.

Comment: Strange, on my just updated gentoo works very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install kde-touchpad
```

and

```
sudo kcmshell4 kcm_touchpad
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a synaptic touchpad, as most do, install the synaptics driver if you have not already, usually called `xf86-input-synaptics`.

Installing the KDE touchpad config modules (usually `kcm-touchpad` or `kde-touchpad`) should provide you with the configuration GUI.

I am actually quite surprised this was not included by default by your distribution, if is ships with KDE by default.